# CKAN: View is empty when inherited from a base controller

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, ckan

I want to change CKAN registration logic, so I inherited from the CKAN UserController class and registered it as a route, but when I try to view the page, the registration form is empty. It shows only header, footer and the title of the form. I didn't create a ./user/new.html file, so I'm still using the ckan template file.

My plugin.py file

```
from ckan.config.routing import SubMapper

class AuthPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin):
    plugins.implements(plugins.IConfigurer)
    plugins.implements(IRoutes, inherit=True)

    def update_config(self, config_):
        toolkit.add_template_directory(config_, 'templates')
        toolkit.add_public_directory(config_, 'public')
        toolkit.add_resource('fanstatic', 'auth')

    def before_map(self, map):

        user_controller = 'ckanext.auth.controllers.user:UserController'
        with SubMapper(map, controller=user_controller) as m:
            m.connect('/user/register', action='register')

        return map
```

User controller class:

```
from ckan.controllers.user import UserController as CoreUserController

class UserController(CoreUserController):

    def register(self, data=None, errors=None, error_summary=None):
        return super(UserController, self).register(data, errors, error_summary)
```

What should I do to make this work?

P.S: As I think the bug is in the ckan ./templates/user.html file, which has a {{ form | safe }} tag. There must be a some kind of context or something that I should set in my controller in order to make it work.

P.S.2: Strange thing is when I do the same thing for Organization controller, it works!!!

Thanks